# How to make the Set size sidebars in Complex Upset the total number of items and the single "intersection" top bar the items only in that set?

Tags: r, ggplot2, upsetplot, complex-upset

When, sing the Complex Upset in R, if `mode="inclusive_intersection"` is chosen (which I need to show) the set size bars end up being the same as the single bars in the intersection size. I expected the side bars to be **all** the items in that group whereas the single intersection bar to be the items exclusively found in that group.

How to make the side bars be the total and the top bars be the items exclusively in that set?

Comment: Could you please share some code you have tried and reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: The [tutorial](https://krassowski.github.io/complex-upset/articles/Examples_R.html#region-selection-modes) demonstrates the expected behaviour for "top bars" (intersection sizes); what you call "side bars" represent the set sizes; the set sizes do not change if you change the intersection mode (by definition). It is not clear what behaviour you are expecting.

Comment: Hey thanks for commenting. The set size is the same for one dot selected is the same as the intersection size when that dot is selected. Why show something twice?